# WPF wrappanel: manage horizontal and vertical behaviour

Tags: wpf, alignment, wrappanel

is there any way to obtain this layout using a WPF Wrappanel? B and C in the pictures should be vertically aligned in horizontal mode and horizontally aligned in vertical mode. Letters orientation must be preserved.
In pictures, from [Horizontal] to [Vertical]:

[Horizontal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FebZz.png)

[Vertical](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvtg8.png)

I've tryed:

```
<wrappanel>
<A/>
<wrappanel>
<B/><C/>
</wrappanel>
</wrappanel>
```

but its behaviuor is unpredictable. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use a Grid?

Comment: Can't you just user Grid, set columns and rows, and set columnSpan/rowSpan on A to 2 ?

Comment: The unique way I've found: adding code in a **SizeChanged** event: `if (this.Height > this.Width) {wrappanel.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal} else {wrappanel.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical}`

Comment: @Clemens no: the Grid constrains B and C in rows or columns.

Comment: @Zeronader the problem is not A, but B and C.

Comment: This could be a 2x2 Grid with RowSpan=2 or ColumSpan=2 for A

Comment: @michele74c So your problem is How to change orientation on some condition, or just to set B and C in same alignment ?

Comment: @Clemens could you write an example? It's not clear to me, sorry

Comment: @Zeronader yes, how to manage Orientation property on resizing. The code answers to this question. What I'm wondering is if there's a "non-coding way" that uses only layout

Comment: You may perhaps want to write a [custom Panel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-create-a-custom-panel-element).

Comment: @Clemens it could be the solution. Even because the layout od the project has become even more complicated, just now... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to be in proper alignment, you can just use Grid like this.
That way B and C will always have same width and height, whenever you resize window.

```
    <Grid>
   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
      <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="*" />
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <Button Content="A" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
   <Button Content="B" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
   <Button Content="C" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I've tryed, but this code always produces a left high button and two right ones. However, resizing does not bring to figure [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvtg8.png)...

Comment: Oh, so you want to change from horizontal to vertical on resize? You should be more clear in your questions.
You can also try using wrap panel, but keep B and C in grid and set minimalWidth on Grid or A, so 2nd item (which will be grid) will move to 2nd row in wrapPanel

Comment: if you use a grid or anything else, the first wrappanel will wrap the contained grid, but the contained objects won't wrap from horizontal to vertical, like in the image. The second wrappanel should solve this problem, but... this is the question. I don't know how to explain better, sorry

Comment: Ok, so right now i can't figure out any solution without code, but with just a little code you can make converter which will convert entire window or A control width to orientation and set it on 2nd wrapPanel